# WDS after installation of Windows 7 64bit, not bootable device found

Tags: windows, deployment, service, wds

When I install Windows 7 (64bit) Enterprise over WDS, it successfully goes through the installation but then when it actually tries to boot from the hard drive where it installed windows, it doesn't recognize it as a valid boot device....

"No bootable device found"

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer.  What else have you tried? Does it only fail on that one machine, or all of them? What does the WDS log say? What kind of drive is it?

Comment: I've tried on two different identical machines, I've also tried a custom made 64 bit version of windows 7 with programs installed on it, how do I pull up the wds log? (Also trying 32bit win7 as we speak)

Comment: Can you browse the drive you just recently imaged, is it formatted? Are the systems files present?

Comment: yes they are present

Comment: is the bootsect file you are using for x86 or x64 bit systems?

Comment: Are you using the same Boot image type as the deployment image? Did you integrate all of the required drivers? Did you break a RAID array (if more than one disk)? Are you installing to the primary disk (if more than one disk)?

Comment: Try running `bootsect /nt60 X:` where `X` is the drive letter of the destination drive where Windows is installed.